# Opening VBA code exchanges characters

Tags: excel, vba, character-encoding, special-characters, excel-2013

I have a problem with some code I have written in an English version of `Excel 2011` for mac. When I open the workbook in `Excel 2013` in Swedish certain Swedish letters in the code get converted to other characters, rendering the code useless. In other words, I have used special characters to define variables (I know, not good practice) and as conditionals (`If x = 'Ombeställning'` for example).

Is there an easy way to force the compiler to read my code as `UTF-8`? I'm on a tight deadline and I really don't feel like retracting all my variable declarations and subsequently changing my defined range names. If there is no other way, please tell me so I can get on changing the code.

Lastly, opening the workbook in `Excel 2013` changed some of the row widths/heights, is this avoidable? I've spent a lot of time on formatting and it simply doesn't look professional when parts of the text are cut off etc.

EDIT: I forgot to mention I am opening 'Excel 2013 ' on a PC, which is probably the culprit regarding character encoding rather than the Excel version language.

Comment: See this related MSDN post:  [VBA character encoding problem between PC/Mac][http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ddd5a465-285e-43ec-a754-76943d093b1f/vba-character-encoding-problem-between-pcmac]